# Failed to read images when folder has special characters on name

Tags: python, path, pyautogui, pathlib

Basically I'm using `locateOnScreen()` function, which is from `pyautogui` to read an image and then find in the screen by:

```
import os
import pathlib
import pyautogui

Image = os.path.join(os.path.sep, pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve(), 'static', 'img', 'game', 'image-btn.png')

if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(BossImg, grayscale=True, confidence=0.95) != None:
    print(True)
```

The code above works prety fine, the problem is when some users, even me because my native language is Portuguese and we have special characters in the language, and we might have some in a folder name.
Let's use this example:

In english:

```
C:\Users\guilh\Desktop\Folder
```

In Portuguese:

```
C:\Users\guilh\Área de Trabalho\Folder
```

So for some cases when we get a folder with accented characters, I'm getting the error:

```
Failed to read C:\Users\guilh\Área de Trabalho\Folder\image-btn.png because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format
```

But why am I gettig this error with special characters if I'm passing the path correctly with `pathlib` and `os`? If I run the same script in the `English` example, works perfectly.

Comment: are the images in same folder?

Comment: Yes! The real problem here is regarding the accented character: `Á` against `A`. In english it works pretty well, but when some user has accent on word, it gives me that error, and I don't know how to treat it.

Comment: How about making a copy of the file into a temp folder (in English, for example  c:\Temp), maybe also consider renaming the file and only then calling locateOnScreen?

Comment: @GuilhermeMatheus I tried using a path containing ``Á`` and it worked fine. What is your version of Python, ``pyautogui`` and ``pyscreeze`` ?

Comment: @Cubix48 really that yours is working? `PyScreeze==0.1.28` and `PyAutoGUI==0.9.53`

Comment: @GuilhermeMatheus Yeah, but that's because I am on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging a bit in the source code of `PyAutoGUI` on Github, it appears that `PyScreeze` is used to detect an element on the screen from an image of it, and it uses openCV's `imread()` function to load the image.

`cv2.imread()` currently does not support pathnames containing Non-ASCII characters on Windows.

A [pull-request](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/pull/53) has already been opened on the PyScreeze repository to use `cv2.imdecode()` instead of `cv2.imread()`.

---

To fix this issue while waiting for the support for non-ASCII characters,

### Method 1

The first option would be to modify the `PyScreeze` package installed (This can be annoying if anyone needs to be able to run the script easily from their computer).

- Identify the location of the `PyScreeze` module:

```
python -c "import pyscreeze; print(pyscreeze.__path__)"
```

- Modify `__init__.py` located in this folder:

Line 21,

```
import numpy as np
```

Line 166,

```
img_cv = cv2.imdecode(np.fromfile(img, dtype=np.uint8), LOAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

Line 168,

```
img_cv = cv2.imdecode(np.fromfile(img, dtype=np.uint8), LOAD_COLOR)
```

- Finally install `numpy`

```
pip install numpy
```

---

### Method 2

As [@SiP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14826251/sip) explained, Another possibility could be to copy the image to a temporary folder.

Something like that:

```
import os
import pathlib
import tempfile
import shutil
import pyautogui

Image = os.path.join(os.path.sep, pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve(), 'static', 'img', 'game', 'image-btn.png')
temp_path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), "file_name_in_ascii")
shutil.copy2(Image, temp_path)

if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(temp_path, grayscale=True, confidence=0.95) is not None:
    print(True)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the solution in the mean time. I noticed that the pull request was open a long time ago, I wish they look at that soon.

Comment: Here is the issue for imread to support non-ascii filenames https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/18305, there is still some activity about this topic :).